# SQL Server : Sumif the criteria is lower or equal then its own value in the same colum

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sumifs

This is my first time on a forum like this, and I really need help.

I have a table looking like this

```
CREW_ITEM_ID | RANK_SORTINGSEQ| YearsInRank
-------------------------------------------
CREW-001     | 204            | 100
CREW-001     | 205            | 200
CREW-002     | 101            | 300
CREW-002     | 102            | 400
CREW-002     | 103            | 500
CREW-003     | 105            | 600
CREW-003     | 106            | 700
```

I have to sum the column YearsInRank (which are actually days but OK) 
by rank and crew item id

A higher Rank (=lower RANK_SORTINGSEQ number) would add of course to the Years in Rank

The result I would like to have form the example above is

```
CREW_ITEM_ID | RANK_SORTINGSEQ| YearsInRank
-------------------------------------------
CREW-001     | 204            | 100
CREW-001     | 205            | 300
CREW-002     | 101            | 300
CREW-002     | 102            | 700
CREW-002     | 103            | 1200
CREW-003     | 105            | 600
CREW-003     | 106            | 1300
```

since e.g.

- CREW-002 103 = 300+400+500 = 1200
- CREW-002 102 = 300+400 = 700
- CREW-002 101 = 300

I have created this in excel and it works but in SQL Server I am lost

```
=SUMIFS(EXP[DURATION],EXP[CREW_ITEM_ID],[@[CREW_ITEM_ID]],EXP[RANK_SORTSEQ],"<="&[@[RANK_SORTSEQ]])/365
```

(Duration = column YearsInRank)

Thanks a lot,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a table variable filled with example data.
You can join this table to itself based on the condition that *per crew (member)* the *rank_sortingseq* of the previous record must be lower.

```
-- generate the example data:
declare @x table (crew_item_id varchar(8), rank_sortingseq int, YearsInRank int)
insert into @x (crew_item_id, rank_sortingseq, YearsInRank) values 
('CREW-001', 204, 100),
('CREW-001', 205, 200),
('CREW-002', 101, 300),
('CREW-002', 102, 400),
('CREW-002', 103, 500),
('CREW-003', 105, 600),
('CREW-003', 106, 700);

-- actual query:
select q1.crew_item_id, q1.rank_sortingseq, q1.YearsInRank, YearsInRank2 = sum(q2.YearsInRank)
from @x q1 join @x q2 
  on q1.rank_sortingseq <= q2.rank_sortingseq and q1.crew_item_id=q2.crew_item_id
group by q1.crew_item_id, q1.rank_sortingseq, q1.YearsInRank
```

The new column YearsInRank2 is the result you expected (I presented both to show the difference).

Comment: Thanks a lot it works great. Wow it was so simple. Thank you.